# Python: store image and associated folder name in a list

Tags: python, loops, machine-learning, classification, glob

I am very new to Python and I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem.

I have a folder "Train" with sub-folders "ball", "chair", "cup", "bag" each sub-folder consists of it associated image.Such as:

```
project/Train/ball/01.jpg
project/Train/chair/02.jpg
project/Train/cup/03.jpg
project/Train/bag/04.jpg
```

I have written the following code to read image from Train

```
names_path = []
training_paths = []

for name in glob.glob('/Train/**/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(name)
    training_paths.append(name)
```

For `names_path = []` I would like to store the name of the sub-folder (bag, chat, cup, ball) of the current image. So if first image in the loop belongs to ball, save image path to `training_paths` and "ball" to `names_path`

I have tried using another loop such as

```
for clas in glob.glob('/Train/*/'):
```

But when I check the list all the entries are None.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add each `p` to `names_path`?  If so, just add `names_path.append(p)` inside your existing loop.

Comment: Where are you running your python script from? Are you already in `Train`?

Comment: If you need to extract parts of the path (like the directory name), have a look at the `os.path` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: @DrewG. No I would like to save the folder name "ball", "chair", "cup", "bag" in names_path. So for example if the first image belongs to "ball", save path of image to training_paths and save ball to names_path

Comment: @Harry.Smith you could add `names_path.append(os.path.basename(os.path.basename(name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `file_path` ist the path of your image you can get the directory name with:

```
from os import path
file_path = "project/Train/ball/01.jpg"
dir_name = path.basename(path.dirname(file_path))  # "ball"
```

- `dirname()` extracts the path of the directory
- `basename()` extracts the last part of the directory path
- See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend where you're actually running the file from, but I think your error is that you don't need the slash just before `Train`.

Change:

```
glob.glob('/Train/**/*.jpg')
```

To:

```
glob.glob('Train/**/*.jpg')
```

Your code is producing an empty list, so the for-loop never runs.